# iOS 15 App icon in Share Extension isn't updated with updating the app icon

Tags: ios, swift

I have a mechanism to update the app icon to a different one. I'm using:

```
UIApplication.shared.setAlternateIconName
```

But I noticed that since iOS 15 app icon in Share Extension (when I want to share something) isn't updated. On iOS 14 and earlier it works fine. Also I see that lots of apps have the same issue.
What's the reason? Can we solve it somehow?

Comment: Welcome to SO - Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve, edit and format your questions. 

Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is impossible to help you troubleshoot.

Comment: And what should I add here?:) I provided all the information. Who knows this topic can understand me without any problems. Thx